# Very poor terminal experience in Windows 10 SSH session

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Windows 10 VM installed in VirtualBox. I installed native OpenSSH server in it. I configured that virtual machine in a way that I can SSH into it. Everything works as expected. But the problem is after connecting the Windows 10 guest trough SSH from my GNU/Linux host, the terminal experience I have is very poor. There is constant shuttering, characters/lines are misplaced and other weird issues. Here are are some things that I tried and didn't work:

- I used different terminal emulators with different TERM variables while connecting: xfce4-terminal, st, urxvt. No combination worked.
- I installed WSL and tried to open `bash` after logging into Windows trough SSH.
- I installed `tmux` trough WSL and `tmux` suffers the same problems.
- Tried to launch `powershell` after SSH login and same problems also happened there.

In Windows 10, the terminal experience is pretty flawless (both `cmd.exe` and `powershell`.) I believe that the issues are related to some inconsistencies between my GNU/Linux host terminal emulator's configuration and windows shell. Maybe there is a `TERM` variable that can solve this issue?

Also one thing that I did not try is installing OpenSSH server trough WSL but I don't believe that would make any difference.

So, how can I solve this?